# Javascript function to write out seconds in string format like this

Tags: javascript, time

I would like a function that can return strings like this:

It takes one input, which is a *number* or a *string*, representing the time value in **seconds**.

If the input is `0`, return `"0s"`.

If the input is `10` (or under 60), return just the number with an "s" at the end: `"10s"`.

If the input is `60`, `120`, `180` etc., return only the number of minutes with an "m" at the end, without seconds: `"1m"`/`"2m"`/`"3m"` (don't display seconds if not necessary).

If the input is `65`, return `"1m05s"` (if there's a number or hour before the second, always display the leading zero).

If the input is `3600`, `7200` etc., then return round hours only with an "h" at the end: `"1h"`/`"2h"` (same logic as with minutes).

If the input is `3661`, then return `"1h01m01s"` (use the same logic on both minutes and seconds: display the leading zero if there's something before the value).

I only need values to display up until hours.

Comment: @jfriend00 This was meant to be a Q&A post, that's why I didn't include that.

Comment: This site isn't meant to be a "please write my code for me" site, though some people will.  It's meant to be a here's what I tried and here's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @jfriend00 Point being, I made this little function and thought I might as well `share my knowledge - Q&A style`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
function toTimeString(num){
    if (typeof num != 'undefined'){
        if (!isNaN(num*1)){
            var mins=parseInt(num/60), secs=num % 60, hours=false,ret={};
            if (num>=3600){
                hours = parseInt(mins / 60);
                mins = mins-(hours*60);
                if (mins < 10 && mins != 0) mins = '0'+mins;
                else mins = false;
            }

            ret.h = (hours?hours+'h':'');
            ret.m = (mins?mins+'m':'');
            if (mins == 0 && !hours && secs == 0) ret.s = '0s';
            else if (secs){
                if (secs < 10 && mins) ret.s = '0'+secs+'s';
                else ret.s = secs+'s';
            }
            else ret.s = '';

            return ret.h+ret.m+ret.s;
        }
        else throw new TypeError("Passed argument is not a number");
    }
    else throw new ReferenceError("No arguments were passed.");
}
```

A little logical explanation:

1. Counting the values

   1. Minutes are equal to the `num` divided by 60 and rounded down
   2. The easiest way to count out the seconds without having to worry about the minute division and what not, just return the remainder of the division of 60 and the `num`
   3. By default, we don't care about hours, so let's just make it `false`
2. Counting the hours

   1. If the `num` is bigger than or equal to 3600, then it's about time to consider the usage of hours. So let's divide the minutes by 60, and round that down too.

      - But if we use hours, we have to work with the minutes in a different way. Let's subtract the hours multiplied by 60 from minutes. Add the leading zero if needed. Also, if the resulting number is `0`, we don't want to display it, so we make it `false`.
   2. If the number is less than 3600, then why bother with the hours? Moving on.
3. Parsing the output

   1. If hours and minutes are `undefined` or `0`, set their values to an empty string, otherwise use their values with `"h"` and `"m"` appended respectively
   2. Parsing seconds

      - If the minutes are `0`, the hour is either `false` or `0` and the seconds is zero too (this happens the input is `0`), return `"0s"`
      - If the seconds aren't `undefined` or `0` and are less than ten, add the leading zero and return them with an `"s"` appended
      - Otherwise if the seconds are bigger than ten, just return them with an `"s"` appended.
      - Otherwise, make it an empty string, since there's noting to display.